# Reading data from text file and returning String

Tags: c#, text

I have a text file that contains the following informations :

> ```
> 1         no mobile
> 2         new mobile
> 641       SonyEricsson_Sunny_Standard_v09
> 643       Nokia_6700s_Standard_v09
> ```

There are no white spaces in the txt file, the first column is the Mobile ID and the second column is the Mobile Type.

I have written a small code that takes the input from the user (Mobile ID) and it should return the Mobile Type. I used Parse function.
Please not that `ID` is `int` and `Type` is `String`.
Here is the small code, but I don't know what is missing to get the string which is the mobile type according to the input by the user.
Thanks for your help

```
int MobileID = 0;
System.Console.WriteLine("Enter Mobile ID in Numbers and press enter");

MobileID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
System.Console.WriteLine("You entered the number:" + MobileID + ".");
Console.ReadKey();

StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Robotron\Execution\MobileID_Type.txt");
string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] fields = line.Split('\t');
    int MobileType = Convert.ToInt32(fields[1]);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

What is missing in order to get the input from the user as the ID and return the type that corresponds to that ID ?

Comment: Can you please make correct indentations! Which language you use? Please tag your language please!

Comment: I am using C# Language

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Robotron\Execution\MobileID_Type.txt");

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    string[] columns = line.Split('\t');
    if(Convert.ToInt32(columns[0]) == MobileId)
    {
         return columns[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just chnage the line : `int MobileType = Convert.ToInt32(fields[1]);`

by : `string MobileType = fields[1].ToString();`

Answer (score -2):

This will work for you.

```
int MobileID = 0;
System.Console.WriteLine("Enter Mobile ID in Numbers and press enter");
MobileID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
System.Console.WriteLine("You entered the number:" + MobileID.ToString + ".");
Console.ReadKey();
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:\\Robotron\\Execution\\MobileID_Type.txt");
string line = null;
while (reader.Peek != -1) {
    line = reader.ReadLine();
    string[] fields = line.Split(ControlChars.Tab);
    if (MobileID == Convert.ToInt32(fields(0))) {
        Console.WriteLine("Mobile Type is:" + fields(1).ToString);
        break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit Do
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Written in Vb.Net and then converted to C#, But I think enough for the OP to get the answer.